# Check code from user input against a list

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I am coding a Vb.NET file in MS visual Studio and need to write some regex's for diagnostic codes for skin cancers. Below are the codes. I've covered the first batch using this basic expression:

```
^([C43\d]|[C44\d]){4}$
```

but now I need to expand it to cover codes which do not have all the digits from 0-9 as the fourth character such as C510, C511, C512, C518, C519, therefore excluding 3,4,5,6,7 in fourth position, and this is where I'm struggling. Can anyone help out please? Thank you.

```
C430
C431
C432
C433
C434
C435
C436
C437
C438
C439
C440
C441
C442
C443
C444
C445
C446
C447
C448
C449
C510
C511
C512
C518
C519
C792
D030
D031
D032
D033
D034
D035
D036
D037
D039
D040
D041
D042
D043
D044
D045
D046
D047
D048
D049
D485
```

Comment: Does it have to be a regex, or can you simply check the number against a list?

Comment: I think you have an error in your existing expression. Bracket characters - [] - are used in regular expressions to indicate a set. So, [C43\d] will match C or 4 or 3 or \d (any digit). This is exactly the same as using [C\d].

Comment: Please clarify: what can each of the four characters be?

From what I understand, the first character has to be one of either 'C' or 'D', the second and third any digit and the fourth may be any digit excluding 3,4,5,6 and 7 (i.e., it may be 0,1,2,8 or 9).

Please confirm or correct this.

Comment: Yeah. To reiterate what @MrGlass just mentioned, your current regex will match any string of length four in which each character may be either the letter 'C' or any digit; this is because it is equivalent to `^([C\d]|[C\d]){4}$` which is equivalent to `^[C\d]{4}$`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the first character has to be one of either 'C' or 'D', the second and third any digit and the fourth any digit excluding 3,4,5,6 or 7 (i.e. any of the digits 0,1,2,8 or 9). If this is so, the following regular expression should do:

```
^([CD]\d\d[01289])$
```

Comment: @ Roney Michael - No that's not entirely true - doesn't your code allow strings through which are not in my explicit list?

Comment: @PaulStevens: Like I said, it will match any string of the format specified in my answer above. If you need any other format string to be matched, tell me what values each character is allowed to assume and I'd be glad to help.

Comment: @PaulStevens: P.S. If you mean a list of ICD-10 codes, just let me know which subset of codes you are trying to extract.

Comment: @ Roney Michael - If I'm using an explicit list as per my original post maybe I should just work with an array of strings to save a lot of ballache. Thank you for your input anyway - I was impressed by the speed and volume of answers I received.

Comment: @PaulStevens: An array of String would be simpler, but more time-consuming to code as well as execute. If however, if it seems to suit your current needs I wish you well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all codes, you can simply make a regex out of the list:

```
(C430|C431|C432|...|D047|D048|D049|D485)
```

Comment: @ Sjoerd - i had thought of that but there must be a cleaner way?